# how spring boot reads values from application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have very generic question, how spring boot understands that it should read values from application.properties?
What will happen if I rename it to some xyz.properties? And, How it intelligently able to distinguish different files (application-dev.properties, application-qa.properties etc)?
What exactly is happening behind the scene?

Comment: The code is open source so you can just look into it to see what it does and how.

Answer (score 1):

> How spring boot understands that it should read values from application.properties?

It understands that because the developers of Spring wrote code to specifically look for a file by that name, as documented in the [Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) section of the [**Spring Boot Reference Documentation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/).

> What will happen if I rename it to some xyz.properties?

Then the file will not be loaded, unless *you* add code to cause it to be loaded, e.g. using [`@PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html).

> How it intelligently able to distinguish different files (application-dev.properties, application-qa.properties etc)?

Spring Boot was coded to look for profile-specific property files for active profiles, as documented in the [Profile-specific Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) section of the [**Spring Boot Reference Documentation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/).

> What exactly is happening behind the scene?

That is too broad a topic to cover here. As [suggested by takendarkk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60743786/how-spring-boot-reads-values-from-application-properties#comment107472659_60743786), the Spring Boot code is open source so you can just look into it to see what it does and how.

Answer (score 0):

Spring maintain order to load property files. please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822326/precedence-order-among-properties-file-yaml-file-and-command-line-arguments-in) for more details