Spring Boot won't pickup application.properties in custom class loader environment
I am currently working on a project which includes running Spring Boot within a Minecraft Spigot / Paper plugin.
My project is setup to run a custom Framework that I built on plugin initialization:
// MyPlugin class

override fun onEnable() {
    MyFramework.run(javaClass, name)
}

My framework is responsible for initializing the Spring application, which works fine...
Dependency injection and any other part of Spring itself works without problems, but one thing bothers me.
I can't get the application.properties file to work with Spring Boot.
Spring seems to just ignore my properties file and any other external configuration file, when declared in my Minecraft plugin....
I have tried multiple things already:

Custom resource loader when building the Spring Application using SpringApplicationBuilder

Setting the properties file location using spring.config.location  when building the application using SpringApplicationBuilder

Adding @PropertySources to the main class of my Spring Application

Manually adding the application.properties file to the output JAR ROOT before running


I have made sure that the configuration file is correctly placed in the ROOT directory of my plugin.
The file is also found by the application proven by the following test:
public static void checkPropertiesFile() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource("application.properties");
    if (resource != null) {
        System.out.println("Found application.properties at " + resource.getPath());
    } else {
        System.out.println("application.properties not found in classpath.");
    }
}

This is the code snippet relevant to running the spring application:
public static void run(Class<?> plugin, String pluginName) {
    final ClassLoader pluginClassLoader = plugin.getClassLoader();

    // needed or else spring startup fails
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(pluginClassLoader);

    final ResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader(pluginClassLoader);
    final SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder();
    // auto generated "main spring class"
    // needed since when using the actual plugin main class, spring tries to instantiate a new instance of our plugin class, which fails
    final Class<?> pluginConfiguration = Class.forName(plugin.getPackageName() + ".PluginConfiguration");
    final Class<?>[] sources = {pluginConfiguration, SpigotConfiguration.class, BungeecordConfiguration.class};

    context = builder.sources(sources)
            .initializers(applicationContext -> {
                applicationContext.setClassLoader(pluginClassLoader);
            })
            .resourceLoader(loader)
            .properties("plugin.name=" + pluginName)
            .properties("plugin.main=" + plugin.getName())
            .run();
}

I am really lost here, you guys are my last hope, I am slowly losing my mind

it may not be helpful, as its a workaround, but you can read that file before starting spring, parse it (probably java buildin Properties class could do it), and then use System.setProperty("key",value). If system property is set, then spring will use it

@mlecz I implemented your suggestion and noticed something weird..
custom property attributes like the ones seen in my post (plugin.name, plugin.main) are picked up by spring but others aren't???
I've tested it by removing my custom properties, which resulted in my application to fail on startup (which is expected since I am registering beans that rely on those configuration values).
Using ConfigurableEnvironment#getSystemProperties() I can see every property set within my configuration file, how is spring not using "spring.profiles.active" to determine the active profiles on startup?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822326/precedence-order-among-properties-file-yaml-file-and-command-line-arguments-in maybe you don't set your envs before spring starts?

btw check those 2 configs: spring.config.location spring.config.name

Both "spring.config.location" and "spring.config.name" are null when checking System properties and spring environment properties

google those configs, you may want to use those

yea even with both properties set to either class path locations or external ones like defined in the spring docs it won't work.
My only guess is that spring doesn't like the custom class loader I provide it with.
Am I missing some crucial dependency or is this possibly a spring internal bug?

I have found a way to kind of resolve my issue.
When telling Spring to use „StandardEnvironment“ while building, Spring picks up any System Property set before starting:
builder.initializers(applicationContext -> {
    applicationContext.setEnvironment(new StandardEnvironment());
})

Now I can use @mlecz s suggestion (Loading the application.properties with a Properties Object and iterating over every key-value pair, then setting a System Property for every pair).
This is a workaround and not directly the functionality I was hoping for, but it works.
Here’s the edited code snippet for anyone having similar issues with implementing Spring in such an environment:
public static void run(Class<?> plugin, String pluginName) {
    final ClassLoader pluginClassLoader = plugin.getClassLoader();
    // needed or else spring startup fails
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(pluginClassLoader);

    final ResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader(pluginClassLoader);
    final SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder();
    final Class<?> pluginConfiguration = Class.forName(plugin.getPackageName() + ".PluginConfiguration");
    final Class<?>[] sources = {pluginConfiguration, SpigotConfiguration.class, BungeecordConfiguration.class};

    System.setProperty("plugin.name", pluginName);
    System.setProperty("plugin.main", plugin.getName());

    try {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.load(pluginClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));

        properties.forEach((key, value) -> {
            System.setProperty(key.toString(), value.toString());
        });
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}

    context = builder.sources(sources)
            .initializers(applicationContext -> {
                applicationContext.setClassLoader(pluginClassLoader);
                // this somehow enables spring to pickup the system properties    
                applicationContext.setEnvironment(new StandardEnvironment());
            })
            .resourceLoader(loader)
            .run();
}


With this implementation I was able to set my active profile with the „application.properties“ which is located in the ROOT of my built JAR

Class loader isolation and resource loading methods that are not aligned appropriately are frequently the cause of the problem wherein Spring Boot fails to load the application.properties file in a custom class loader environment. You can identify and fix the problem more successfully if you make sure the right class loader is used, specifically set the configuration file location, and enable debug logging.
This is an updated example of setting the explicit configuration file location for the Spring Boot application:
public static void run(Class<?> plugin, String pluginName) {
final ClassLoader pluginClassLoader = plugin.getClassLoader();

// needed or else spring startup fails
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(pluginClassLoader);

final ResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader(pluginClassLoader);
final SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder();
final Class<?> pluginConfiguration = Class.forName(plugin.getPackageName() + ".PluginConfiguration");
final Class<?>[] sources = {pluginConfiguration, SpigotConfiguration.class, BungeecordConfiguration.class};

context = builder.sources(sources)
        .initializers(applicationContext -> {
            applicationContext.setClassLoader(pluginClassLoader);
        })
        .resourceLoader(loader)
        .properties("spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties")
        .properties("plugin.name=" + pluginName)
        .properties("plugin.main=" + plugin.getName())
        .run();

}
